# Submit por Javascript no ejecuta metodo post

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp

Tengo un formulario en una vista, que al final envío con un botón y JavaScript, y en mi controlador tengo una función POST para recibir ese formulario, el problema es que nunca entra al método con el botón y JavaScript, pero si lo cambio por un botón de tipo Submit, si entra al método, ¿Qué falta en mi función de JavaScript?.

Nota: La intención es que al enviar el formulario con JavaScript, recoja en un arreglo todos los checkbox que están seleccionados.

Formulario:

```html
<form id="formcoordi">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead class="text-center">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID Scrap</th>
                    <th scope="col">User</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Model</th>
                    <th scope="col">Element</th>
                    <th scope="col">Station</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cause</th>
                    <th scrope="col">Treatment</th>
                    <th scope="col">Approval</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-center">
                @foreach(var item in listascrap)
                {
                    string cadenacausa = "";
                    string cadenatrata = "";
                    foreach (var itemt in listascraptrata)
                    {
                        if (item.IDScrap == itemt.IDScrap)
                        {
                            cadenatrata = String.Concat(cadenatrata,"/",itemt.Tratamiento);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var itemc in listascrapcausa)
                    {
                        if (item.IDScrap ==itemc.IDScrap)
                        {
                            cadenacausa = String.Concat(cadenacausa,"/",itemc.Causa);
                        }
                    }
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.IDScrap</td>
                        <td>@item.Usuario</td>
                        <td>@item.Fecha</td>
                        <td>@item.Modelo</td>
                        <td>@item.elemento</td>
                        <td>@item.estacion</td>
                        <td>@cadenacausa.ToString()</td>
                        <td>@cadenatrata.ToString()</td>
                        <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=@item.IDScrap></td>
                    </tr>                    
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button type="button" onclick="Checkedboxes()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background: #ff8000;">
            Enviar
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Función en JavaScript:

```
function Checkedboxes()
{
    let ids = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        //cada elemento seleccionado
        ids.push(this.value)
    });
    var form = document.forms['formcoordi']
    form.submit();
}
```

Y mi controlador con metodo POST

```
public ActionResult Index(int [] ids)
        {
            foreach (var item in ids) 
            {
                var idparametro = new SqlParameter("@ID_Scrap", ids[item]);
                _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"EXEC sp_Coordinador_Autoriza @ID_Scrap", idparametro);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Gracias por tu interés

Answer (score 1):

En el backend:

```
[HttPost] // Esta parte falta. 
public ActionResult Index([FromBody] int [] ids) // También el lugar de donde estás obteniendo los IDs, que en este caso es desde el cuerpo de la petición
        {
            foreach (var item in ids) 
            {
                var idparametro = new SqlParameter("@ID_Scrap", ids[item]);
                _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"EXEC sp_Coordinador_Autoriza @ID_Scrap", idparametro);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

En el frontend:

```
<form action="URL a donde envías la petición" method="post"> // Cuando no se especifica, es un GET by default.
```

Answer (score 0):

Me detendré a usar Jquery puesto que veo que lo usas.

Personalmente dejaría de usar el formulario nativo de HTML y pasaría a un formulario asíncrono, haciendo un par de trucos. El problema con el envío de tu información es que jamás le pasaste la data al formulario, por eso no la envía. Y peor, El `submit` de `form` no se detendrá a que hagas un ciclado con Jquery, solo se enviará y ya, independiente si tienes que hacer lógica o no. A parte, a tu `input` le falta la propiedad `name="ids[]"` para que pueda ser reconocido por el formulario como un arreglo, pero reitero, no podrías enviar únicamente los checkeados.

Para eso te dejo este código que te resolverá el problema de asincronía. Combínalo con la respuesta de fredyfx, puesto que yo se muy poco de C#

```js
// Creamos un listener que esté atento cuando el form se envíe
$( document ).on('submit', '#form', function(event){
    // Cancelamos la naturaleza de submit del form para hacer lógica antes deenviar
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const ids = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        ids.push(this.value)
    });
    // Hasta aquí ya tendríamos los checkboxes únicamente los checkeados
    console.log( ids );
    // Abrimos una conexión asíncrona y llenamos un par de parámetros
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      method: 'POST',
      // Si te das cuenta el payload que se enviará se llama ids, que concuerda con tu parametro de llegada en el backend
      data: { ids },
      // Tu backend debería responderte algo si fue un éxito, será cachado en esta función
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response )
      },
      // Si hay algun error que envíes tu, o que el browser detecte caerá en esta función
      error: function( error ) {
        console.log( error.statusText )
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <br><button type="submit">Enviar</button>
<form>
```

Te comparto la bibliografía para que te adentres un poco en este tema.

[$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)